# how to set up database after installing lamp stack using vagrant

Tags: mysql, wordpress, vagrant

i have set up my local dev environment using vagrant and a lamp stack on my virtual machine.

the only problem is i have no idea how to set up a mysql database so i can get wordpress working. specifically, i need to know what the database name, user and password are for the wordpress config.php file.

this server stuff is not really my area of expertise and the explanations on google are alls bit technical and i can't understand whats gong on.

at the moment i have no idea if i have even set ups database. is there any way of doing that and checking when i enter the VM when using `vagrant ssh`

also, i know there are out of the box solutions available like VVV but i am trying to learn how this stuff actually works so i want to do it manually for now.

any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have to start for [this source](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/getting-started/provisioning.html), and then keep going with examples like [this](http://misheska.com/blog/2013/06/16/getting-started-writing-chef-cookbooks-the-berkshelf-way/).

I hope this help.